# Cannot display google advertising ID

Tags: java, android

I'm setting an Info object adInfo to

```
Info adInfo = null;
adInfo = AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(currContext.getapplicationContext()).  
gaidContent.setText(adInfo.getId());
```

And it's not displaying the Google ad ID.

Comment: Have you seen this post? :[Using Advertising ID in Android](http://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2014/01/16/advertising-id-android-kitkat/)

Comment: Yes, I have. I did everything it says in the article but it's still not displaying. The adInfo I get seems to be NULL.